# jmeter returns undefined as output

Tags: angularjs, node.js, jmeter, postman

I send over data from my Angular JS to my node API in following manner:

**Inside Angular:**

```
$http({

    method : "POST",
        url : '/add',

    data : {
            "a" : $scope.a,
                "b" : $scope.b
               }

}).success(function(data) {

    $scope.result = data.result;


}).error(function(error) {

    $scope.result = 'Invalid data...';

});
```

**Inside my nodejs API definition:**

```
exports.execute = function(req, res){

    var a = req.body.a;
    var b = req.body.b;

    var result;

    result = Number(a) + Number(b);

    var json_responses;

    console.log('from api add');
    console.log((a));
    console.log(b);
    console.log(result.toString());

    json_responses = {"result" : result.toString()};

    res.send(json_responses);

};
```

The API and angular work just fine when I enter values from browser, the actual values are printed on the console.

But, when I try to post data using POSTMAN or use data for JMETER load balance testing, the console prints data as **"undefined"**.
The ways I tried defining the data are:

```
data={
   a : 100,
   b : 100
}


data={
   "a" : "100",
   "b" : "100"
}

data={
   "a" : 100,
   "b" : 100
}
```

Anything that I am missing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set header `Content-Type` and value must be `application/json` to accept in `req.body` while `Content-Type` sent by AnguarJS is `application/json` by default

Comment: what about postman?
I tried adding content type in HTTP Header Manager, but it stopped showing any values in the requests at the console. Please guide.

Comment: It should work, you may try `res.json(json_responses);`

Comment: setting the content-type was all I required.